# Exporting certificates on Microsoft IIS 2019 ver 10

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, iis-10

I have Imported an SSL certificate in Windows 2019 Server, IIS ver 10.
When I right click on the certificate from IIS, the "Export" option is missing.

Is there any way to bring this option back or try exporting it from command line?

[image]

Comment: Does the export attribute was set  ? As it need to be set to be able to export it

Answer (score 1):

You can of course export this certificate from the mmc `certificates`.

Run `CertLM.msc` to open your local computers certificates and locate it by opening the `Certificate Store` it mentions in the list in the IIS Manager.

```
Rightclick > Task > Export
```

**The associated private key will only be exportable if it has been marked to be so at the time of the import.**

Your certificate will also be downloadable by just visiting the website with no option to get the private key with.